# Python Ensure File ends in line return?

Tags: python, file

I would like to have a function which takes in a path to a file, checks if the file ends in an `\n`, and add in a `\n` if it doesn't.

I know that I could do this by opening the file twice, once in read mode and then again in append mode, but I feel like I must be missing something... I feel like `'w+'` mode, for example, must be able to do it.

Here's a way of doing this opening the file twice (I want something simpler where you only open it once).

```
def ensureFileEndsWith(path, end):
    with open(path) as f:
        f.seek(-1, 2)
        alreadyGood = f.read(1) == end
    if not alreadyGood:
        with open(path, 'a') as f:
            f.write(end)
```

I want to do the same thing, but only opening the file once. I tried this:

```
def ensureFileEndsWith(path, end):
    with open(path, 'w+') as f:
        f.seek(-1, 2)
        if not f.read(1) == end:
            f.write(end)
```

But it printed out this exception:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Regarding my usage of `seek` in a file opened in `'w+'` mode.

Comment: From the 2.7 docs - ```(note that 'w+' truncates the file)```.

Comment: @wwii: Huh - that sucks. My entire file is gone now. It was just a log file, and I don't think I had anything important in it, but now it's empty.

Comment: Always backup before doing anything that could mess up your files! :)

Comment: @Cyphase - I actually got it back. I was fortunate enough that I had loaded the file into memory in a Python REPL already, so I just wrote that back out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you want `open(path, 'r+')`; `'w+'` truncates the file. The reason you were getting that error is because you can't do `f.seek(-1, 2)` into an empty file. This should do it for you:

```
def ensureFileEndsWith(path, end):
    with open(path, 'r+') as f:
        try:
            f.seek(-len(end), 2)
        except IOError:
            # The file is shorter than end (possibly empty)
            f.seek(0, 2)

        # Passing in a number to f.read() is unnecessary
        if f.read() != end:
            f.write(end)
```

Comment: Not quite right - I edited your answer. Your answer didn't handle the possibility that the file already ends with the right character, in which case the function should just close the file and return.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, thanks for pointing that out. I further improved the code to allow for variable-length `end`.